# Pygame Sprite. How to create different enemies/images from same class?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am building a tiny platform based game with Pygame. I want to go from having one graphic for my enemies, to several different graphics. My idea was to put them all in an array and draw randomly from it upon initing to get several sprites with randomly picked graphics.

But the result is I get either enemy1.png or enemy2.png for all the sprites. I am not sure if this is really simple and I am just not able to see it, or if I need to extend the enemy class for each new graphic I want the enemies to have?

I tried two things which are essentially the same, and I get the same result from both.

First idea:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    enemyArray = [pygame.image.load('enemy1.png'), pygame.image.load('enemy2.png')]

    def __init__(self, location, *groups):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(*groups)

        for i in self.enemyArray:
            self.image = choice(self.enemyArray)

        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(location, self.image.get_size())
        self.direction = 1
```

Second idea:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    enemyArray = [pygame.image.load('enemy.png'), pygame.image.load('bomb.png')]
    for i in enemyArray:
        image = choice(enemyArray)

    def __init__(self, location, *groups):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(*groups)

        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(location, self.image.get_size())
        self.direction = 1
```

I've used the internet to find some guidance, but I can't find anything that seems to handle this issue. Anything is helpful, from ready made code snippets to links that might enlighten me.

Update:

```
class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        ...
        self.enemies = tmx.SpriteLayer()
        for enemy in self.tilemap.layers['triggers'].find('enemy'):
            Enemy((enemy.px, enemy.py), self.enemies)
        self.tilemap.layers.append(self.enemies)
```

I use a tilemap that I've created in Tiled, so for each enemy-trigger, there is an enemy spawning. Is this enough?

Comment: could you please show how you instantiate and use your Enemy class?

Comment: Yes, is that helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second idea you have a line:

```
image = choice(enemyArray)
```

This should not work because you are making a local variable image, that will not be stored into Enemy class at all. But you don't have this error in the first idea. The correct way to set an attribute is like this:

```
self.image = choice(enemyArray)
```

Then you can change:

```
 for i in enemyArray:
     image = choice(enemyArray)
```

into:

```
image = choice(enemyArray)
```

because it should make no difference, you are just throwing a dice 2 times when you have 2 pictures in enemyArray.

Comment: The idea is to have 10 different enemies, behaving the same, but looking different. The goal of the game is simply to kill the enemies, and having them looking different is just for my own pleasure. But yes, that's the same thing, but your suggestion does not do what I want it to.

Comment: Yes, i've tried to cut down the code and replaced enemyArray with `[1,2]` and i was able to generate different choices in 2 instances, could you please show more code?

Comment: I am not storing the enemies in a list, they are generated onto the tilemaps triggers for enemies.

Comment: How does your trigger generation look like? do you just set `xyz = Enemy` somewhere? (without parenthesis and arguments) This would make reference to a single Enemy instance that exists after you declare the class, hence all of them will have the same picture.